# How to obtain the square root of the transition matrix of Markov

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

Suppose 
$$Q = \{q_{ij}\}$$
with $\sum\limits_j q_{ij} = 1,\quad |q_{ij}|\leq1$
is the transition matrix of a Markov chain. Then how to find the square root of $Q,$ namely
$$R^2 = Q.$$
One way I used is using the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{x},$ since every entry of $Q$ is smaller than $1,$ then $Q^n$ should be convergent. But is there any better way to computer the square root of a matrix?

Comment: It's not "the" square root, but rather "a" square root: in general, a matrix has a lot of square roots. Maybe, you want the square root to be a stochastic matrix as well, then it is a different story. In any case, you should try to use the Jordan decomposition.

Comment: @zhoraster It's a deterministic matrix. But even for the Jordan form, it's not easy to obtain the square root.

Comment: By a stochastic matrix, I mean a one having non-negative entries and row sum 1. A transition matrix, if you like. For a Jordan matrix, it is rather straightforward to compute a square root.

Comment: @zhoraster That's my matrix.

Comment: What's "that's" your matrix? 

Concerning the Taylor expansion, note that there is no Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{x}$ at zero. If you expand around another point, this is quite tricky.

Comment: The problem of finding a stochastic square root to a stochastic matrix (where again, a "stochastic" matrix is just a "transition" matrix; all matrices here are deterministic) is very non-trivial.  [Here is a paper](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/papers/hili11.pdf) on that very problem

Answer (score 5):

The problem of finding a stochastic square root to a stochastic matrix (where again, a "stochastic" matrix is just a "transition" matrix; all matrices here are deterministic) is very non-trivial.  [Here is a paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379510001849) on that very problem (this paper talks about finding $p$th roots, but finding square roots isn't all that much easier than the general case).

Notably, fact 4.1 says that there exist some transition matrices that have no square roots *of any kind*, let alone those that happen to be transition matrices themselves.  For instance, 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&1}
$$